# Why my private static Map is empty on execute when it is filled in the constructor in apex batch class?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

In the following code:

```
    global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    ...
    private static Map<String, Id> mailTemplates = new Map<String, Id>();

    private void initMailTemplates() {
        if(mailTemplates.size() == 0) {
            List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE name IN ('template1', 'template2', 'template3', 'template4', 'template5')];
            for(EmailTemplate mailTemplate :templates) {
                String templateName = mailTemplate.Name;
                Id templateId = mailTemplate.Id;
                mailTemplates.put(templateName, templateId);
            }
        }
    }
...
```

When `initMailTemplates()` method is invoked in the constructor then my Map `mailTemplates` is empty in the execute method.

If `initMailTemplates()` method is invoked in the beginning of the execute method the Map `mailTemplates` is filled with the necessary elements.

Why my private static Map is empty on execute when it is filled in the constructor in apex batch class?

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250378/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A batch class's `start()` method, each invocation of its `execute()` method, and its `finish()` method all take place in separate transactions. Static variables are always reset across transaction boundaries in Salesforce; you cannot expect your Map to persist across transactions.

If you wish to maintain state across `execute()` invocations, implement the [`Database.Stateful`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) marker interface. Note however that this still **does not** persist `static` variables. You'll need to move your state into a non-static member variable to persist it.